# check input fields with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

i am using the following code to check if user doesnt input special characters in name

```
    var regex = /^[a-zA-Z ]{2,50}$/;//check for only letters
    var ctrl = document.getElementById('input1');//given name field 
    if(!regex.test(ctrl.value)) 
    {
        alert('Ensure field Name contains only letters[A-Z]');
        return;
    }
```

1. can someone please help to change regex so client can also enter JUST one (')(IF NEEDED) e.g O'Daniel.
2. also for phone no field limit user with only one +

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you want to allow `+`? How many chars did you want to allow after adding `+`? Your current regex will allow spaces at the last. Is this the right behaviour?

Comment: Just to be clear: you want to exclude *everyone* that is a descendant of or related to (by marriage for example) a 'foreigner' with a 'special' name? People (potential clients) who might very well live next door to you? (Note to future readers: **don't** do this: limiting to A-z for people's *names*)

Comment: [This](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask) can be an option.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to cram all the logic into a single regexp. To check for apostrophes, simply do a separate check:

```
var apostrophes = ctrl.value.match(/'/g);
return !apostrophes || apostrophes.length < = 1;
```

Use the same logic to check for no more than one `+` in the phone number.